# Failed to connect to TensorFlow master: TPU worker may not be ready or TensorFlow master address is incorrect

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, bert-language-model, pre-trained-model, tpu

I signed up for the Tensor Research Cloud (TRC) program for the third time in two years. Now I barely created a preemptible v3-8 TPU. Before that, I could efficiently allocate five non-preemptible v3-8 TPUs. Even with this allocation (preemptible and non-preemptible), the TPU is listed as **`READY`** and **`HEALTHY`**. However, when I try to access it from the pretraining script, I run into this error that I have never encountered before:

```
Failed to connect to the Tensorflow master. The TPU worker may not be ready (still scheduling), or the Tensorflow master address is incorrect.
```

I know that the TensorFlow master address is correct, and I have checked that the TPU is healthy and ready. I have also double-checked that my code is correctly creating the TensorFlow session and specifying the TPU address.

What could be causing this error message, and how can I troubleshoot and fix it?

I also tried this code from https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tpu. Note that I'm not using Colab but using Google Cloud Platform.

```py
resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu='pretrain-1')
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)
# This is the TPU initialization code that has to be at the beginning.
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
print("All devices: ", tf.config.list_logical_devices('TPU'))
```

Any I'm stuck at:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Initializing the TPU system: pretrain-1
```

However, I expected something like this:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Deallocate tpu buffers before initializing tpu system.
2022-12-20 13:08:56.187870: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:267] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected
INFO:tensorflow:Deallocate tpu buffers before initializing tpu system.
INFO:tensorflow:Initializing the TPU system: grpc://10.99.59.162:8470
INFO:tensorflow:Initializing the TPU system: grpc://10.99.59.162:8470
INFO:tensorflow:Finished initializing TPU system.
INFO:tensorflow:Finished initializing TPU system.
All devices:  [LogicalDevice(name='/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:0', device_type='TPU'), LogicalDevice(name='/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:1', device_type='TPU'), LogicalDevice(name='/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:2', device_type='TPU'), LogicalDevice(name='/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:3', device_type='TPU'), LogicalDevice(name='/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:4', device_type='TPU'), LogicalDevice(name='/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:5', device_type='TPU'), LogicalDevice(name='/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:6', device_type='TPU'), LogicalDevice(name='/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:7', device_type='TPU')]
```

**Edit:** I successfully accessed the TPU with the same configurations from a new Tensor Research Cloud (TRC) account. However, the problem is still ongoing with the previous TRC account. I suspect it might be a problem with the Google Cloud Platform (GCP) configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by deleting all TPUs and VM instances and then disabling and reenabling all APIs.

The issue might be related to the VPN connection to a GPU cluster during enabling services.

Comment: How did you do that, write it down so other people can benefit from it. commands like `gc.collect()` or just deleted/destroyed the vm

Answer (score 1):

In the preemptible TPUs documentation, you can see a note in the [Detecting if a TPU has been preempted](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/preemptible#detecting_if_a_tpu_has_been_preempted) part.

**Note:** If your Cloud TPU is preempted, you must delete it and create a new one as described in [Managing TPUs](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/managing-tpus-tpu-vm).

*Finally Check [Supported TPU configurations](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/supported-tpu-configurations)

Also refer to the official Document[Troubleshooting TensorFlow - TPU](https://Troubleshooting%20TensorFlow%20-%20TPU) for more information.

Comment: `ctpu up` is deprecated and tries to create a v2-8 TPU by default. I already run the code on a Google Compute VM instance. I tried every step in the troubleshooting to no avail.

Comment: Oh, Can you check combinations of preemptible, tensorflow versions?

Comment: Please check [Supported TPU configurations](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/supported-tpu-configurations)

Comment: I got this error to `Deallocate tpu buffers before initializing tpu system` , would this help 
in that or I would have to use `gc.collect()` or something like that